# OnClick doesn't appear to be getting called

Tags: java, android, onclick

I am trying to open a web browser window onclick of a button.

My click event doesn't appear to be getting called.  LogCat shows no errors or any evidence of it being called.  I have a feeling this is due to me having 2 methods named '`onClick`', but removing the second method causes an error.  I can fix this error by making MainActivity abstract, but that crashes the app.

I feel this is a simple fix, but after pouring over documentation and several tutorials I cannot find the answer.

Code is below, followed by my manifest.  Thanks in advance.

```
package com.spotsofmagic.spotsofmagic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "Activity...";
    private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        // grab our NFC Adapter
        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        // TextView that we'll use to output messages to screen
        mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        //displayMessage("Loading payload...");

    }

    private void displayMessage(String message) {
        mTextView.setText(message);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // do something when the button is clicked
        displayMessage("Loading broswer");
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://www.***.com/");      
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);  
        startActivity(launchBrowser);  

        if(v.getId() == R.id.btnVisitWebsite) {

        }
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

And the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.spotsofmagic.spotsofmagic"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name=".CardActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <!-- Handle a collectable card NDEF record -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.spotsofmagic.spotsofmagic"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
         </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `OnClickListener` but you didn't attach it to any button. Try

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id)).setOnClickListener(this);
```

**EDIT:** The other problem is, that you implemented `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` instead of `View.OnClickListener` in your `Activity`.

Remove the imports

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

And add

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

You can also remove

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

after this.

Comment: That makes sense, but: `findViewById(R.id.btnVisitWebsite).setOnClickListener(this);` inside `MainActivity` causes various errors ("Not applicable for the arguments").  Am I doing something obviously erroneous?

Comment: Cast `findViewById(R.id.btnVisitWebsite)` to a `Button` like in my code. `((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVisitWebsite)).setOnClickListener(this)`

Comment: I was getting "`Multiple markers on this line - Button cannot be resolved to a type"`.  That's why I changed it to the code above.  I am still getting that error with your code and the amended imports.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should import `android.widget.Button` too.. Press Ctrl+Shift+O in eclipse, to resolve all the missing imports.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.  Quite obvious I guess, but I'll put it down to experience.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't associate the click event.

If you are binding it to button (or) something, you need to do bind it for 'this'

Example:

```
   button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion, you could also do it using the XML if you are not creating the view programatically. You can do something like this.

```
<Button android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" android:onClick="openBrowser" />
```

and provide the method in your program as

```
public void openBrowser(View v)
{
   /*  do your stuff here */

 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll +1 for the different option.  I'll keep it future-proofed and do it programatically though.